# Bug while getting the longest sequence from 2D Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm almost done with the code where the method returns the longest sequence of the objects that have the same element. If my 2D ArrayList `myBoard` looks like this:

```
    |  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0 | 11| 11| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12| 12|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  1 |  o|  o|  o|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  2 |  b|  b|  b|  b|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  3 | 11| 11| 11| 11| 11| 11|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  4 |  b|  b|  b|  b|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|  ~|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  5 | 11| 11| 12| 12| 12|500| 12|480| 12| 12| 12| 12|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

then the method longestHorizontalSequence() should return

```
[(0,2,12), (0,3,12), (0,4,12), (0,5,12), (0,6,12), (0,7,12),....(0,11,12)]
```

but instead my method returns:

```
[(0,0,11), (0,1,11), (0,2,12), (0,3,12), (0,4,12), (0,5,12), (0,6,12), (0,7,12),.....,(0,11,12)]
```

i.e. it returns the longest sequence of the whole line. I've tried to debug but cannot guess what I should change in my code. Could smb please take a look? Thanks in advance!

```
public List<RowColElem<T>> getHorizontalSequence(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard){
     ArrayList<RowColElem<T>> result = new ArrayList<RowColElem<T>>();

     int count = 1;
     int max = 1;
     int row1 = 0;
     int col1 = 0;
     for(int i = minRow; i <= maxRow; i++){


         List<RowColElem<T>> currentList = new ArrayList<RowColElem<T>>();
         RowColElem<T> obj = new RowColElem<T>(i, minRow, myBoard.get(i-minRow).get(0));
         T elem = obj.getElem();
         currentList.add(obj);

         for(int j = minCol + 1; j <= maxCol; j++){

             row1 = i - minRow;
             col1 = j - minCol;
             if(elem.equals(myBoard.get(row1).get(col1)) 
                     && (!(elem.equals(this.element))) 
                     && (!(myBoard.get(row1).get(col1).equals(this.element)))){


                 count++;
                 RowColElem<T> obj1 = new RowColElem<T>(i,j, myBoard.get(row1).get(col1));
                 currentList.add(obj1);
                 obj = new RowColElem<T>(i, j, myBoard.get(row1).get(col1));

                 if(count > max){
                     max = count;
                    /* while(max != 0){
                         currentList.remove(max--);
                     }*/
                 }

                 if(currentList.size() > result.size()){
                     result.clear();
                     result.addAll(currentList);
                 }
             }

             else{

                 if(obj.getElem().equals(this.element)){
                     currentList.remove(0);
                 }
                 elem = myBoard.get(row1).get(col1);
                 obj = new RowColElem<T>(i,j, elem);
                 currentList.add(obj);

                 count = 1;

             }
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Class `**RowColElem**`

```
public class RowColElem<T>{

    private int row;
    private int col;
    private T e;

    // Create a RowColElem with the parameter parts
    public RowColElem(int r, int c, T e){
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
        this.e = e;
    }

    // Return the row
    public int getRow(){
        return this.row;
    }

    // Return the column
    public int getCol(){
        return this.col;
    }

    // Return the element
    public T getElem(){
        return this.e;
    }

    // Return a pretty string version of the triple formated as
    // (row,col,elem)
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + this.row + "," + this.col + "," + this.e.toString() + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the correct output be:
[(0,2,12), (0,3,12), (0,4,12), (0,5,12), (0,6,12), (0,7,12),...(0,11,12)] in the form of: (row, column, value)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, shouldn't the correct output go from (0,2,12) to (0,11,12) instead of (0,7,12)?

Comment: @Sterls, yeah you're right this time too, sorry for that! I posted the board from previous test run. Fixed it!

Comment: @Sterls, my code is missing smth but cannot understand what

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
else{

             if(obj.getElem().equals(this.element)){
                 currentList.remove(0);
             }
             elem = myBoard.get(row1).get(col1);
             obj = new RowColElem<T>(i,j, elem);
             currentList.add(obj);

             count = 1;

         }
```

Try:

```
else{
             currentList.clear();
             elem = myBoard.get(row1).get(col1);
             obj = new RowColElem<T>(i,j, elem);
             currentList.add(obj);

             count = 1;

         }
```

If I am correct, You are not clearing your `currentList` arraylist properly so it is holding on to the entire row, rather than the set you want.

Alternatively, it will be simpler to forgo the entire RowColElem class and simply keep track of the start position and longest horizontal sequence at each position. It can easily be done in 2 for loops where you increment the longest subsequence variable each time the object to the left is equal to the current object. Everytime you move forward, check if that number is > max and thus store the start position of the sequence, and the current position (the end of the sequence).